# how to dispatch async actions using typesafe-actions?

Tags: typescript, react-redux

I'm using **typesafe-actions** on my react.js project
I'm trying to change my actions from standard actions to async actions using **createAsyncAction**.

this is my code:

actions/users.ts

```
export const fetchUserStatus = createAsyncAction(
   'FETCH_USER_REQUEST',
   'FETCH_USER_SUCCESS',
   'FETCH_USER_FAILURE'
)<void, any, any>();
```

components/userStatus.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchUserStatus } from '../actions/user';

type Props = {
    fetchUser: () => any;
};

class UserStatus extends React.Component<Props> {
    render() {
        this.props.fetchUser();
        return (<div/>);
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = () => ({});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    fetchUser: fetchUserStatus.request(),
})(UserStatus);
```

When I try to compile it I receive the following error:

```
Error:(31, 4) TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof UserStatus' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<Shared<{ fetchUser: EmptyAction<"FETCH_USER_REQUEST">; }, Props>>'.
  Type 'typeof UserStatus' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<Shared<{ fetchUser: EmptyAction<"FETCH_USER_REQUEST">; }, Props>>'.
    Type 'typeof UserStatus' provides no match for the signature '(props: Shared<{ fetchUser: EmptyAction<"FETCH_USER_REQUEST">; }, Props> & { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any> | null'.
```

Since I'm still very new to typescript, I don't know how to solve it. When using standard actions my coding is working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

ok, this is one of those moments when you change your code and do typos:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    fetchUser: fetchUserStatus.request(),
})(UserStatus);
```

should be:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    fetchUser: () => fetchUserStatus.request(),
})(UserStatus);
```

Comment: Probably not relevant to the OP, but there's also:  
---
`export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    fetchUser: fetchUserStatus.request,
})(UserStatus);`